# Custom url protocol for OSX desktop app using electron by atom

Tags: macos, protocols, desktop-application, electron, custom-url

I am new to dekstop app by electron. However i built a desktop app using [this source code](https://github.com/SebastianSzturo/basecamp-desktop) and just changing the links to my site. Now I have a functional desktop app for mac.

But i want to open my app using a link say **appName://and-some-link-follows**

How can i implement custom url schema to open dekstop app whenever i click **appName://....**

For example:
I want to do something like Slack desktop app which opens up by clicking **slack://and-some-link**

Any help please. Stuck here for 2 days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

1. Do a build for your app
2. Right click -> show package content
3. In info.plist add the following

[image: Can't pase code. So in image]

4. Open app once to register customURL into system.

In terminal enter **/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump|egrep "(bindings.*:$)"|sort** to check wheather yours is in the list.

Comment: I have accomplished to pass myapp://param with 'url-event, on an running instance. But haven't yet made to start myapp by entering myapp://param URL scheme from Safari/Chrome etc!

Comment: Basically my app just starts but without passing URL scheme! When app instance exist it passes the scheme!

Answer (score 2):

Today I faced a similar thing and upon doing some researching, I found [this useful tutorial](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/electron-app-with-custom-protocol/) on how to do it. It explains everything thoroughly and I think it might be useful for others facing the same issue. This is the highlights:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const protocol = electron.protocol
// handles links `todo2://<something>`
const PROTOCOL_PREFIX = 'todo2'
function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1000, height: 800})
  protocol.registerHttpProtocol(PROTOCOL_PREFIX, (req, cb) => {
    const fullUrl = formFullTodoUrl(req.url)
    devToolsLog('full url to open ' + fullUrl)
    mainWindow.loadURL(fullUrl)
  })

}
```

Also there's a guide on how to build for both **OSX** and **Windows** at the end of the post I linked.

For those who'd like to read a bit more, here's a link to the [official docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md).